# How to use Akka.Streams.*.ConcatMany in F#?

Tags: f#, akka.net, akka.net-streams

I want to create a flow that creates a new source (it will be a persistence query) out of incoming elements, and then flattens the results. Something like this simplified example:

```cs
var z = Source.Single(1).ConcatMany(i => Source.Single(i));
```

this code compiles and works as expected. My problem is that when I translate it to F#:

```ml
let z = Source.Single(1).ConcatMany(fun i -> Source.Single(i))
```

I get an error saying

```
This expression was expected to have type
    'IGraph<SourceShape<'a>,Akka.NotUsed>'    
but here has type
    'Source<int,Akka.NotUsed>'
```

I think that the cause of that is that F# handles co/contravariance differently than C# and cannot simply convert these generic specializations (https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/162), but I cannot figure out a way to make a convertion between an `int` and a `SourceShape<int>`. Is it possible to convert this example to F#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [the code on GitHub](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/blob/c1c65780bb65efcd4b2057f9b3d57d6017fa07ca/src/core/Akka.Streams/Dsl/Source.cs), it appears that `Source<TOut, TMat>` is a direct implementation of `IGraph`, so you should just be able to cast it:

`public sealed class Source<TOut, TMat> : IFlow<TOut, TMat>, IGraph<SourceShape<TOut>, TMat>`

`let z = Source.Single(1).ConcatMany(fun i -> Source.Single(i) :> IGraph<SourceShape<int>,Akka.NotUsed>)`

I think the biggest difference between the C# and F# usage is that C# will automatically do the upcast for you.

Comment: This also works with inferred type, like that: `let z = Source.Single(1).ConcatMany(fun i -> Source.Single(i) :> _)`

Comment: You can just use F# `upcast` as well.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround that I found is to use [Akkling.Streams](https://github.com/Horusiath/Akkling) wrapper library:

```ml
open Akkling.Streams

let x =
    Source.singleton 1
    |> Source.collectMap(fun x -> Source.singleton x)
```

the question how to do this without Akkling remains open.